# CSS body fixed background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this CSS:

```
body
{
    background-position: center top;
    background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-image: url('Background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: inherit;    
    top: 0px;
}
```

When I maximize window it's all ok but when I make the window smaller, the background image moves.

[This is how look in maximizedbrowser window](http://s15.postimage.org/7yzy9yiln/image.png)

[And this is after change window size](http://s15.postimage.org/elro096ln/image.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most answers you will get from people requires IE9+ (since it is CSS3). However, if you expect users be using older browsers as well (I am being practical and safe here), I think the way you need to do this is by using jQuery/JavaScript. I did something similar in the past in CSS3, but I realized later that most corporate/companies still use IE8 and the best way to do this is using JavaScript.

Here are a few examples:

1. http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html 
   (this is a great example)
2. http://designshack.net/?p=13616
3. http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/jquery.php

Answer (score 0):

TRy This:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position:fixed;
```

Comment: Problem with this is that setting it to fixed takes the DOM element out of the normal position and therefore 'cover' adapts to the body rather then the element. Can't seem to find a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, try to group your CSS Properties together where available as such:

```
body {
width: 1000px;
height: 1200px;
background: #EDEDED url('Background.png') center top inherit no-repeat;
top: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
font: .85em "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
color: #696969;
}
```

Could you also provide a jsFiddle to the issue so we may see the entirety of the code, or a link to the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/

Thanks